# babel taking a long time to copy a entire html-template

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm build a project with Node+Electron and it's being built with Babel with this command:

`"private:compile": "babel app/ --copy-files --out-dir build",`

It's working fine. The problem started when I downloaded a HTML template that has 40mb of JS and CSS and put everything in public assets dir. Now babel takes a long to compile project because it's many many many files.

Is there any way to make babel ignores compiling and simply copy some certain files? Or make babel ignore files that hasn't changed?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel usually looks for a .babelrc in the current folder and if it finds one it searches for a setting like:-

```
{
 "ignore": [
    "foo.js",
    "bar/**/*.js"
  ]
}
```

That setting will ignore the files being looked up. 
If .babelrc does not exist, it will travel up the directory tree until it finds either a .babelrc, or a package.json with a "babel": {} hash within.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--verbose` flag on the end to see where it gets stuck. For me it is quick to transpile the target files. I am using `--ignore "node_modules"` and can see it ignores them for the transpile step.

After this it hangs for a good 50 seconds. This started happening after upgrading to version `^7.0.0` it is currently using `7.10.5` of the `@babel/cli